# Blocking an app programmatically

Tags: java, android

I followed an answer here on StackOverflow, but I am having some difficulties. I have the code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> appList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent,0);
    Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
    List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i=0; i<packs.size();i++){
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        ApplicationInfo a = p.applicationInfo;

        if((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1){
            continue;
        }
        apps.add(p.packageName);

        ActivityManager mActivityManager =(ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
        Intent lockIntent = new Intent(mContext, LockScreen.class);
        lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(lockIntent);

        Intent startHomescreen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startHomescreen.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startHomescreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(startHomescreen);
    }
```

Where I having difficulties is that android studio is saying that `apps` in `apps.add(p.packageName);` is not defined, also `activityOnTop` in`activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();` is also not defined. Finally, `lockscreen` in `Intent lockIntent = new Intent(mContext, LockScreen.class);` is not defined can anyone please help me in fixing these problems? Keep in mind that this is all in the `onCreate` method, should I move it to a different class?

Comment: And where is `apps` defined ?

Comment: Does that need to be a string value?

Comment: Since you treat it as a variable, where is it declared ? did you simply add `apps.add(p.packageName);` to your code and hoped for the best ? or did you copy your code from somewhere and forgot to copy the part where `app` is declared as well ?

Comment: @alfasin Oh, I think I get it now, but how do I declare the apps variable?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134740/1057429